# Altering RStudio Editor Theme

Tags: css, themes, rstudio, ace-editor

I am trying to alter an RStudio Editor Themes so that I can set my own colors. I'm using RStudio version 0.99.473 on Windows 10.

I've reviewed [Any way to change colors in Rstudio to something other than default options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25582588/any-way-to-change-colors-in-rstudio-to-something-other-than-default-options) which was extremely helpful as well as [Editing R Studio them in cashe.css theme file (ACE editor?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37635237/editing-r-studio-theme-in-cache-css-theme-file-ace-editor)

I am trying to identify what the different .ace_ items in the RStudio Editor Theme CSS files (ACE editor code) correspond to. The CSS files are found in /www/rstudio/ within RStudio's install path. An example of the script is found on [GitHub for the Tomorrow theme](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/blob/54cd3abcfc58837b433464c793fe9b03a87f0bb4/src/gwt/src/org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/source/editors/text/themes/tomorrow.css).

In particular, I'm looking to see how to color variables (that I define) differently from functions. For example in x <- rnorm(10,0,10), I'd like x and rnorm to be colored differently. Not sure if that's possible.

Answer (score 5):

For what it's worth, the newest versions of RStudio come with a preference that allow you to ensure that function calls are colored differently from variables -- from RStudio v1.0.44, we have the option

- Highlight R function calls

[image: RStudio Options]

With this option active, function calls will be highlighted differently (for example, with Tomorrow Night Bright):

[image: Image Example of Highlighting]

Hopefully, user-customizable themes will become part of the next RStudio release.

Answer (score 2):

RStudio has a [tutorial](https://rstudio.github.io/rstudio-extensions/rstudio-theme-creation.html). Although not specific to your question about coloring variables, I did edit the highlighting of matched brackets in my theme so that they are more visible. Here's how:

Select a theme from [this theme editor](https://tmtheme-editor.herokuapp.com/#!/editor/local/undefined) and save it to your machine as a `.tmTheme` file. Add the theme in RStudio. RStudio automatically creates an `.rstheme` file from that. I found the `rstheme` file in my `Users/Eric/Documents/.R/rstudio/themes` folder (Windows machine). Open the file in Notepad++ (or your favorite text editor) and find the `.ace` entry that matches the one you want to change (for me, specifically, `.ace_bracket` from the RStudio tutorial I mentioned earlier). This will have an rgba value similar to: `background-color: rgba(238, 252, 81, 0.8);`  Note that the last value is the alpha (transparency) value and should be between 0 and 1. The values I used give me a nice bright yellow that is easily seen.

Comment: I found my imported `.rstheme`(s) under `~/.config/rstudio/themes`

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for customising the RStudio theme and I think in that case
You can check out the following link:
This website gives you several options to customize 
https://tmtheme-editor.herokuapp.com/#!/editor/theme/Azure
This is how it works

[image: click to have a look] 
Once you are done customizing download them.
Later you can add the theme in the "add" options while setting a theme in your RStudio

Hope this was helpful 
Happy Coding :)

Comment: The app is now hosted at https://tmtheme-editor.glitch.me/

Answer (score 1):

I found (2022) the theme files in

C:\Users\<my user>\AppData\Roaming\RStudio\themes