# Set the Rstudio theme info in .Rprofile file

Tags: r, rstudio

Is there a way to set the Rstudio Theme info in .Rprofile file?

I see lots of references on how to change the editor theme using the Rstudio IDE.  https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/115011846747-Using-RStudio-Themes  and this SO responce: [Altering RStudio Editor Theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40369595/altering-rstudio-editor-theme)

I would really like to port my preference as part of my .Rprofile file to each new projects as I work on them or as part of a container build.

The current theme values can be viewed using the  function `getThemeInfo()` from rstudioapi, but have no idea how to set the theme or the $editor, $global, and $dark theme parts of the theme info.

```
> rstudioapi::getThemeInfo()
$editor
[1] "Merbivore"

$global
[1] "Modern"

$dark
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rstudioapi::applyTheme(theme_name)`

So applying `Dracula` theme include the following in your `.rprofile`:

`rstudioapi::applyTheme("Dracula")`